# Calling layoutSubviews to dynamically resize a uilabel within a uicollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to resize a `UILabel` frame in a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. I `added the label to the cell in Storyboards`. The frame gets adjusted in `-layoutSubviews`. The frame is getting resized when layoutSubviews is called, `but it isn't displaying the resize when the cell is displayed`.

Here's what I'm assuming based on what I've seen...

1. It seems as though calling -layoutSubviews forces a re-layout on
   every cell in the CollectionView, which hurts performance.
2. With auto-layout on, you simply can't resize the label.
3. If I delete the label in Storyboards, create the it
   programmatically, and set the frame when the cell is called in
   `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it works like a charm.

Are my assumptions above correct, and if so, is there an alternate to -layoutSubviews better suited for CollectionViews.

Comment: Did you try in some other method like viewDidLoad??

Comment: call viewDidLoad to resize a label inside a collectionviewcell??

Comment: When you use auto layout, you're not supposed to set any frames. You change the size or location of a view by adjusting and/or making new constraints. Whether there's a better alternative, depends on what it is you're trying to do. Why are you changing the frame?

Comment: @rdelmar Got it. I'm changing the UILabels height based on it's text. I went ahead and added it programmatically, so it's working now. What about calling -layoutSubviews on UICollectionViewCell? Is that something to avoid?

Comment: I'm not sure about calling layoutSubviews, I don't think I've ever found the need to do that on a table view cell. When I use an expandable label, I just pin it to the top and bottom of the cell (or other UI elements if present), and return a cell height based on the label's text, so it expands with the cell.

Comment: That's a good idea, and other posts say resizing should be done in 'willDisplayCell' which appears to be better than layoutSubviews as well. Thanks @rdelmar.

Comment: Did you call `[super layoutSubviews];`?

Comment: Using auto layout is in this process: updateConstraints, layoutSubviews,updateConstraints, layoutSubviews ....  In this process ,after layoutSubviews , if the frame is not fit to the constraints you set, the process will be called again. So when you use autoLayout, it better not to set frame directly.